# Solution of a first order linear homogeneous ODE with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I was trying to show that if $A:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{nxn} \text{ } $  has a eigen pair $(\lambda(t),v) \text{ }$ with $v$ constant, 
then $x(t)=e^{\lambda t}v$ is a solution of the system $\dot{x} = A(t)x$

Since $$x'(t) = e^{\lambda(t) t}v(\lambda'(t)t+\lambda(t))$$
Then $$\dot{x} = A(t)x \Leftrightarrow e^{\lambda(t) t}v(\lambda'(t)t+\lambda(t)) = A(t)e^{\lambda(t)t}v$$
$$\Leftrightarrow v(\lambda'(t)t+\lambda(t)) = A(t)v$$
$$\Leftrightarrow v(\lambda'(t)t+\lambda(t)) = \lambda(t)v$$
$$\Leftrightarrow v\lambda'(t)t = 0$$

And because $v$ is an eigenvector of A we now that $v\neq0$.

Then  $x(t)=e^{\lambda t}v$ is a solution of $\dot{x} = A(t)x \text{ }$ whenever $\lambda'(t)t=0$

This is where I got stuck.

Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE:

As mentioned in the comments, following the same reasoning as above, it can be shown that $x(t)=e^{\int_{t_0}^{t}\lambda(s)ds}v$, with $\lambda(t_0) = 0$ is a solution of $\dot{x} = A(t)x$

Comment: the right formula is $x(t)=exp(\int_0^t \lambda(s) ds)v$, that's why you got stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is not true. Consider for example the case $n=1$ with $A(t) = t$, $\lambda(t) = t$ and $v = 1$. Then $x(t) = e^{t^2}$, so that
$$\dot{x}(t) = 2te^{t^2} \neq te^{t^2} = A(t)x.$$

EDIT: Also notice the formula given by user8268 in the comments.